# How to combine data replicates for PCA visualization

Tags: python, replication, pca

I have a dataset where each sample/row is a unique protein and that protein is quantified across 7 features/columns. This dataset includes thousands of proteins and will be classified by machine learning (Support Vector Machine). To give an example of the data:

| Protein | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Feature 3 | Feature 4 | Feature 5 | Feature 6 | Feature 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Protein 1 | 10.0 | 8.7 | 5.4 | 28.0 | 7.9 | 11.3 | 5.3 |
| Protein 2 | 6.5 | 9.3 | 4.8 | 2.7 | 12.3 | 14.2 | 0.7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Protein N | 8.0 | 6.8 | 4.9 | 6.2 | 10.0 | 19.3 | 4.8 |

In addition to this dataset, I also have 2 more replicates that are structured the exact same and have the same proteins for a total of 3 replicates. Normally if I wanted to visualize one of these datasets, I could transform my 7 features using PCA and plot the first two principal components with each point/protein colored by its classification. However, is there a way that I can take my 3 replicates and get some sort of "consensus" PCA plot for them?

I've seen two possible solutions for handling this:

1. Average each feature for each protein to get a single dataset with N rows and 7 columns, then PCA transform and plot
2. Concatenate the 3 replicates into a single dataset such that each row now has 7x3 columns, then PCA transform and plot

To clarify what's being said in solution 2, let's call Feature 1 from replicate 1 Feature 1.1, Feature 1 from replicate 2 Feature 1.2, etc.:

| Protein | Feature 1.1 | ... | Feature 7.1 | Feature 1.2 | ... | Feature 7.2 | Feature 1.3 | ... | Feature 7.3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Protein 1 | 10.0 | ... | 5.3 | 8.4 | ... | 5.9 | 9.7 | ... | 5.2 |
| Protein 2 | 6.5 | ... | 0.7 | 6.8 | ... | 0.8 | 6.3 | ... | 0.7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Protein N | 8.0 | ... | 4.8 | 7.9 | ... | 4.9 | 8.1 | ... | 4.7 |

What I'm looking for is if there's an accepted solution for such a problem or if there's a solution that's more statistically sound. Thanks in advance!